# Sorting on Mysql by string and number

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have 3 fields such as **title**, **name** and **size**
I am trying to sort string column (containing numbers).

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+
+----- title -----+---- name ----+-------size--------+
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+
+     SPR-235     + SPR 235      + 118 x 118 x 43 mm +
+     SPR-355-D   + SPR 355 D    + 140 x 140 x 41 mm +
+     SPR-355-K   + SPR 355 K    + 140 x 140 x 41 mm +
+     SPR-415     + SPR 415      + 155 x 155 x 50 mm +
+     SPR-455-K   + SPR 455 K    + 138 x 138 x 64 mm +
+     SPR-455-D   + SPR 455 D    + 138 x 138 x 64 mm +
+     SPR-135     + SPR 135      + 60 x 60 x 82 mm   +
```

I used this query:

**SELECT title,name FROM table ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(' ',name)+1) AS SIGNED)**

It works fine like this:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
+----- title -----+---- name ----+
+-----------------+--------------+
+     SPR-135     + SPR 135      +
+     SPR-235     + SPR 235      +
+     SPR-355-D   + SPR 355 D    + <-- see
+     SPR-355-K   + SPR 355 K    + <-- see
+     SPR-415     + SPR 415      +
+     SPR-455-D   + SPR 455 D    + <-- see
+     SPR-455-K   + SPR 455 K    + <-- see
```

but when I change the query into:

**SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(' ',name)+1) AS SIGNED)**

Unfortunatelly, the "D" and "K" was failed to sort. And show like this:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+
+----- title -----+---- name ----+-------size--------+
+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+
+     SPR-135     + SPR 135      + 60 x 60 x 82 mm   +
+     SPR-235     + SPR 235      + 118 x 118 x 43 mm +
+     SPR-355-D   + SPR 355 D    + 140 x 140 x 41 mm + <-- see
+     SPR-355-K   + SPR 355 K    + 140 x 140 x 41 mm + <-- see
+     SPR-415     + SPR 415      + 155 x 155 x 50 mm +
+     SPR-455-K   + SPR 455 K    + 138 x 138 x 64 mm + <-- see
+     SPR-455-D   + SPR 455 D    + 138 x 138 x 64 mm + <-- see
```

I want to sort "D" first then "K".
Big thanks to help this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the number part then get the last char from the string and order by both in sequence should work.

```
  SELECT name 
    FROM myTable 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(' ',name)+1) AS SIGNED), 
         SUBSTRING(name,-1);
```

[**Live DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e910/1/0)

Comment: @RiaD thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake ;) it lead me to test it to make sure when it would fail and if it would be viable to his needs.

Answer (score -1):

Add another clause to your order by including the substring at character 9 (if it exists).

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name,LOCATE(' ',name)+1) AS SIGNED), 
         SUBSTRING(name,9,1)
```

Comment: What if the number is bigger than 3 digits ? 9 would fail.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know anything about the data.  The key take-aways were a) that you can sort by more than one thing and b) the syntax for doing it.

Comment: You don't need to know the data to know how to get the last char of it however with your example it would not work if for example the number is bigger. That's why I use `SUBSTRING(name,-1)` for instance as it will capture the last char.

Comment: Yup, I think that 'SUBSTRING(name,-1)' really helpful to get the last char. Million thanks for  all :)